# Ionic 2 - Database content is not clickable

Tags: php, jquery, ionic2

I am adding data from database to my ionic2 application here is a piece of code of the php file:

```
if(!empty($oefening1) && !empty($rep1) && !empty($set1)){
    echo "<ion-card class='card card-md nextPage1'><img src='assets/img/" . $oefening1 . ".jpg'/>
             echo "<ion-card-content class='card-content card-content-md'
                            <ion-card-title class='card-title card-title-md'>" . $oefening1 ."</ion-card-title>".
                            "<p> Herhalingen:" . $rep1 . "<br> Sets:". $set1 . "</p>".
                    "</ion-card-content></ion-card>"; 
            }
```

and what I tried was this:

```
<ion-card (click)="test()"></ion-card>
```

But this is not working.

this is my ajax call where i store the data locally with localForage:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:  "http://sylvanreinieren.com/fysioWebapp/php/get_schema.php",
    data: { dataString: tokenValue },
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
        $('#myDiv').html(data);

        localForage.setItem('getSchema', data).then(function (data) {
            // Do other things once the value has been saved.
            console.log(data);
        }).catch(function(err) {
            // This code runs if there were any errors
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
  });
```

That works fine as you see I give an nextPage1 class with it. But when I try to use this in my application it is not working the function look like this:

```
 ionViewDidLoad(){
    $('.nextPage1').click(function () {
       console.log('worked');
       this.navCtrl.push(ExercisePage);
    });
}
```

So the data is loaded and is there with the class but it seems it couldn't pick it up to handle an click event. Why is that? It seems like it can't detect the elements but I think thats weird because I load them like this:

```
ionViewWillEnter(){
 localForage.getItem('getSchema', (err, data) => {
  if(data){
    $('#myDiv').html(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: you should be using [angular](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/) rather than jquery.. ionic 2 is built on angular 2

Comment: I know but I load the ion-card in my php file and couldn't add an click function in there

Comment: also ionic 2 doesnt have any real support for server side js..not sure if sending template from php will work alsways..

Comment: The card is getting picked up but I can't handle an click event

Comment: So thats why I want to do it with jquery but that seems not to work

Comment: As @suraj said, you shouldn't be using any backend to generate html markup. You better change your structure: change the PHP layer to respond some data (maybe json?) and use it in the the ionic layer, with the built-in template engine from ionic/angular.

Comment: @ChristianBenseler How can I pass the json data with an navparam?